# При сохранении формы происходит Insert вместо Update

Tags: python-3.x, django

Добрый день. Вникаю в Django.

```
#models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()

#forms.py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

#views.py
def edit_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if  form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('detail_view', pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/addpost.html', {'form': form})
```

Вопрос в следующем: при сохранении производится INSERT а не UPDATE, перерыл кучу аналогичных вопросов и ответов - код идентичен (все говорят что работает именно в таком виде) может я что-то очевидное упускаю?

```
#template
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'edit' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-default">Править</a>
    <a href="{% url 'delete' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-default">Удалить</a>
    <h2>{{ post.title }} {{ post.datetime }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
{% endblock %}

#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PostsListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_view'),
    url(r'^add/$', new_post, name='add'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', edit_post, name='edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', del_post, name='delete'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Забавно, только запостил вопрос и нашел ошибку тут же.

Надо было использовать такой шаблон:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}edit/" method="POST">
        <div class=""row>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                <div>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.as_p}}
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Сохранить" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

А я использовал шаблон для добавления новой записи :) add
Может это stackoverflow так положительно подействовал ))